Is there a standard/portable way to query if a symbol stands for a symbol macro?
As the title says, how do I (programmatically) check in a portable way (if possible) if a symbol stands for a symbol-macro?
CL-USER> (define-symbol-macro some-macro some)
SOME-MACRO
CL-USER> (macro-function 'some-macro)
NIL
CL-USER> (fboundp 'some-macro)
NIL

SBCL has sb-impl::info:
CL-USER> (describe 'sb-impl::info)
SB-INT:INFO
  [symbol]

INFO names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (CATEGORY KIND NAME)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (T T T) (VALUES T T &OPTIONAL))
  Source file: SYS:SRC;COMPILER;GLOBALDB.LISP

INFO has a compiler-macro:
  Source file: SYS:SRC;COMPILER;EARLY-GLOBALDB.LISP

(SETF INFO) names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (NEW-VALUE CATEGORY KIND NAME)
  Declared type: (FUNCTION (T T T T) (VALUES T &OPTIONAL))
  Source file: SYS:SRC;COMPILER;GLOBALDB.LISP

(SETF INFO) has a compiler-macro:
  Source file: SYS:SRC;COMPILER;EARLY-GLOBALDB.LISP

Seems to work:
CL-USER> (sb-impl::info :variable :kind 'some-macro)
:MACRO
T

That is what they use in the source code for the 'describe' function (I founded by looking there).
Prior to that I was looking at clhs but didn't found anything. Have I missed it or is there no standard way? Is there some portable/"trivial" library that does it?
Edit:
After helpful answer, I have found a "trivial" wrapper for cltl2. It seems to be in quicklisp too, so we can have in addition to built-in 'special-operator-p':
(defun special-variable-p (symbol)
    (multiple-value-bind (info ignore1 ignore2)
        (variable-information symbol)
      (declare (ignore ignore1 ignore2))
      (eq :special info)))

(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol)
    (multiple-value-bind (info ignore1 ignore2)
        (variable-information symbol)
      (declare (ignore ignore1 ignore2))
      (eq :symbol-macro info)))

I actually prefer a generalized boolean, seems more useful, so I am using this:
(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol)
  "Return if SYMBOL stands for a symbol macro."
    (multiple-value-bind (info ignore1 ignore2)
        (variable-information symbol)
      (declare (ignore ignore1 ignore2))
      (when (eq :symbol-macro info)
        (multiple-value-bind (expansion ignored)
            (macroexpand symbol)
          (declare (ignore ignored))
          expansion))))

CL-USER> (symbol-macro-p 'some-macro)
SOME

Edit 2: The simplest and portable way, as shown by Gwang-Jin Kim: (macroexpand-1 'symbol)
(macroexpand-1 'some-macro) => (some T)


You don't need all those multiple-value-bind's, btw - common lisp discards extra values and just keeps the first when not explicitly looking for extras.

(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol) (eq :symbol-macro (variable-information symbol)))

There is an easier way which works in all Common Lisp implementations, because we use macroexpand-1.
We use the fact that macroexpand-1 returns T when expansion happened and NIL when not.
Therefore, only if the call of the symbol itself is a symbol-macro, the expression (macroexpand-1 my-symbol-macro) would return T as the second value, since the macroexpansion would take place when calling the symbolmacro's name itself.
In all other cases it would return NIL as the second value.
So actually, macroexpand-1 when called with a symbol itself is somehow symbol-macro-p. But since macroexpand-1 does a lot more than just symbol-macro-p (it expands also composed macro calls), it might make sense to give this specific function an extra name (symbol-macro-p):
(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol)
  "Return T as the second value, if symbol is a symbol-macro. The first value is then the expanded symbol. If NIL is the second value, the first value can be ignored."
  (macroexpand-1 symbol))

Test
(define-symbol-macro some-macro some)
(defmacro bar (x) `,x)
(defun foo (x) (+ x 1))
(defparameter baz 1)

(symbol-macro-p 'some-macro)  ;; => SOME   T
(symbol-macro-p 'bar)         ;; => BAR    NIL
(symbol-macro-p 'foo)         ;; => FOO    NIL
(symbol-macro-p 'baz)         ;; => BAZ    NIL

So, only in case of a symbol-macro, we get T as the second value.
and in this case, we can take the first value as its expanded symbol.
In all other cases, the answer of the second value is NIl.
Boolean Return
To simplify the function, we could also use:
(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol)
  (multiple-value-bind (expansion result) (macroexpand-1 symbol)
    (declare (ignore expansion))
    result))

Boolean Return and Expansion
or we could also use:
(defun symbol-macro-p (symbol)
  "Return T or NIL as the first value and as the second value,
   if symbol is a symbol-macro the expanded symbol, otherwise NIL."
  (multiple-value-bind (expansion result) (macroexpand-1 symbol)
    (if result
        (values result expansion)
        (values nil nil))))

which returns the results:
* (symbol-macro-p 'some-macro)
T
SOME
* (symbol-macro-p 'bar)
NIL
NIL
* (symbol-macro-p 'foo) 
NIL
NIL
* (symbol-macro-p 'baz)
NIL
NIL


Wonderful! Didn't know that about macroexpand-1. Turns out that even macroexpand can be use the same way.  The standard says it: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm. I just tested, and it seems to work. Both ordinary macros and special operators return NIL. Thank you. I should have known this before :).

Welcome! Well, if symbol-macro would refer to another symbol-macro, then macroexpand-1 would show which symbol-macro it refers to, but macroexpand would show the end symbol after all macroexpansions. So actually, macroexpand-1 is what we want (is more intuitive).

I see, thank you!

There's a function VARIABLE-INFORMATION¹ that was in CLtL2, but not the Common Lisp standard, that at least some CL implementations support, that can be used to tell if a symbol has a symbol macro.
In SBCL, it's accessed via:
CL-USER> (require :sb-cltl2)
("SB-CLTL2")
CL-USER> (sb-cltl2:variable-information 'some-macro)
:SYMBOL-MACRO
NIL
NIL

Clozure has it in the CCL package:
CL-USER> (ccl:variable-information 'some-macro)
:SYMBOL-MACRO
NIL
NIL

Allegro lists it in its documentation but I don't have a copy to test.
LispWorks has it in the HCL package per its documentation, but again I don't have a copy of it.
As @myname discovered, it's available in a trivial-cltl2 package so you don't have to handle figuring out what package the function lives in yourself, making it easier to use across multiple implementations.

1: Found this function in an answer from Rainer about a different question about how to tell if a variable in special when I was looking for a duplicate.

Indeed. Thank you very much. I actually at some point used to to check if a symbol is special operator, but totally forgot about it.

I found this "trivial" wrapper: https://github.com/Zulu-Inuoe/trivial-cltl2 in a quick look at cliki. In that case we can have at least somewhat portable 'special-variable-p' and 'symbol-macro-p' in addition to the standard 'special-operator-p'.
